# How to fill a column depending on the values of two other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns  that hold similar information, and  I want to  merge   those two  in to one column.

How can I merge  two columns  in  to one  the following  way ?

```
Example 

+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  Col 1     |   Col2      |   RESULTING COLUMN  |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  User1     |   User1     |       User1         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  User2     |   User2     |       User2         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  User3     |   N\A       |       User3         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|  N/A       |   User4     |       User4         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IF`. For example:

```
=IF(OR(A1=B1, B1="N/A"), A1,
IF(A1="N/A", B1, "Other"))
```

EDIT: didn't realize the values were actual errors instead of the character string "N/A". In that case, you can use something like

```
=IF(OR(A1=B1, ISERROR(B1)), A1,
IF(ISERROR(A1), B1, NA()))
```

Comment: This Solution only  got me values  when   A and B   had data  and  when A had  data  and B  had error. However in the case wen  B had  data   and  A had error it did  not work

Comment: Thanks  for the  help this did the work !

Comment: `=IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=TRUE,ISERROR(O2)=FALSE),O2,IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=FALSE,ISERROR(O2)=TRUE),N2,IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=TRUE,ISERROR(O2)=TRUE),"N/A",IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=FALSE,ISERROR(O2)=FALSE),N2))))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  =INDEX(A2:B2,MATCH(FALSE,(A2:B2="N\A"),FALSE))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3cLB.png

Comment: I was thinking something like `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B2,NOT(ISERROR(A2:B2))),1)` but your version is shorter, since the MATCH will already show the first result, which is already unique. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help!  I managed to solve this using the following  formula

`=IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=TRUE,ISERROR(O2)=FALSE),O2,IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=FALSE,ISERROR(O2)=TRUE),N2,IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=TRUE,ISERROR(O2)=TRUE),"N/A",IF(AND(ISERROR(N2)=FALSE,ISERROR(O2)=FALSE),N2))))`

Comment: You can shorten to ```=IF(OR(N2=O2, ISERROR(O2)), N2, IF(ISERROR(N2), O2, NA()))``` I believe. Didn't realize your values were actually errors instead of the character string "N/A".

Comment: thanks  will  try.. sorry , I did  not  explain  N/A  were errors  !

Comment: No worries, hopefully it will help in the future!